# Unknown Vs Code Plugin

Tags: plugins, visual-studio-code

[image]

Does anyone know what this plugin is? I don't have anything installed of this sort and I can't select it to even google what it is. It only has this one checkbox option in the settings. If anyone can read this then please tell.

Thank You

Comment: if you hover over the option you get a tooltip with the name of the extension

Answer (score 0):

Could you try reverifying if you don't have anything unrequired installed in your extensions ? try going to the extensions accessible from the left panel or use the shortcut `Ctrl + Shift + X` to go to Installed Extensions